# Inner Join, if not exists create empty columns

Tags: sql-server, join

I am working on 4 tables. The tables all hold data about routes (IE: `From`, `To`, `Distance`).
`Table1` may hold 5000 rows, `Table2` has 2500 rows, `Table3` has 3000 rows and `Table4` has 3000 rows as well.

I have created **INNER JOINs** for all tables. This though, excludes data from `Table1` as `Table1.RouteId` has an entry, but this data may not exist in `Table2`.

I need to compare all the data, and if `Table1.RouteId` is not in `Table2`, then it should just fill the columns of `Table2` like "Not existing" or something like that so I can see that the data is missing in `Table2`, but does exist elsewhere.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at `LEFT JOIN` clause.

Comment: As pointed, your friend is `LEFT JOIN`. And the second friend is `ISNULL` which allows you to set a default value for not existing (`NULL`) values

Comment: Here is a [link to Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx) on the different types of joins and how to use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Comment: And the [wiki info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join)

Comment: That worked! Thank you :D!!

Answer (score -2):

```
select * from A; 
select * from B; 
select * from C; 
select * from D; 

select * 
from A 
left join B on A.col1 = B.col1 
left join C on A.col1 = C.col1 
left join D on A.col1 = D.col1 
order by A.col1;
```

col1

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

col1

```
2 
3 
4
```

col1

```
1 
2 
3
```

col1

```
3 
4 

col1  col1  col1  col1 

1     NULL  1     NULL 
2     2     2     NULL 
3     3     3     3 
4     4     NULL  4 
5     NULL  NULL  NULL
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It might help Raam if downvoters could post their reasons.  I expect these will include poor formatting and a lack of descriptive comments.

Comment: I was wondering the same :( Truth is I don't have enough time to make it look pretty.

Comment: If you dont have time to write a proper answer, my advice is to not bother.